Get the next feature in an atlas and filtering those features on map
So, I have prepared an Atlas report with a polygon layer coverage that contains exclusion areas of the National Ecological Reserve. For each area (each record in the exclusion areas layer) Atlas Layout displays a fixed table with data driven information about the area.
What I would love to do is create a Layout with two or three areas per page, to reduce the number of pages in my appendix.
The only information I've been able to find about this scenario is one slightly arcane post on stack exchange:
Get the next feature in an atlas using QGIS
It works for me despite having some difficulties with code.
Now my difficulty involves to create a symbology based on rules that shows not only the elements (the polygon, in this case) within the current atlas (n) ["fid" = @atlas_featureid] but also the next feature atlas (n+1).
I thought about adding the created variable "atlas_next_feature" to the polygon layer, but I'm not getting the desired result.
Any advice or tips?


My best bet would be to create multi-polygon features collecting those two-to-three areas that you try to show in the same page and saving them to a new layer. After that you would only need to use it as the new atlas cover layer.

Thanks for your response. But i have 200 hundred polygons. Instead of having 200 pdfs for each area polygon, what I would like to have are 2 polygons per page, to end up with 100 pdfs, and none of them repeated.

The answer you refer to does exactly what you ask for. You should share what you have done and  where the formulas don't give you the expected result

@Kasper i did it yesterday! It works! Now my difficulty involves the need to create a symbology based on rules that shows not only the elements (the polygon, in this case) within the current atlas (n) ["fid" = @atlas_featureid] but also the next atlas (n+ 1). .

You should open another question for that
